Playwright- Dropdown não fechando sozinho após escolher opção
Estou aprendendo Playwright, então pode ser uma pergunta boba kkkk
Tenho esse campo, mas após ele selecionar o valor, ele não está fechando sozinho
await page.locator('#report-form svg').first().click(); //aqui ele ta abrindo o campo
await page.getByText('- LOJA GUARULHOS').click();
await page.locator('#report-form path').first().click() //aqui ele deveria fechar o campo

como fazer para fechar após selecionar o valor??
Imagem

Você testou await page.click('body'); depois da seleção da opção? muitas vezes clicar fora do dropdown o fecha.
